# this.props.history.push() no longer seems to work in React Router v4, what's the alternative?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm new to React, and most of the tutorials I see about redirecting using React Router seem to be using the aforementioned snippet. What I am trying to achieve is to redirect the user to the home page of my website upon successful login. I have tried history.push but according to my google searches, it doesn't work in Router v4 anymore. What can I do as an alternative? I'm open to both stateful and stateless solutions.

To clarify, here's the workflow -

1. User fills in a textbox with their username
2. User fills in a textbox with their password
3. User hits the submit button
4. An API gets called with the username and password to authenticate the user
5. The API returns success for successful login
6. Upon successful login, the user is redirected to the home page

Comment: did you find any soloution I am also face same issue.

Comment: @PriyankaSankhala I have switched to using function components now and use hooks instead of this. Try declaring `const history = useHistory()` and using it.

Comment: Here's all about hooks if you need to start somewhere - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

`history.push('./path')` is still usable in React Router v4 you need to add `withRouter`

example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import compose from 'recompose/compose'

class Test extends Component {
  render () {
    const { history } = this.props

    return (
     <div>
       <Button onClick={() => history.push('./path')}
     </div>
    )
  }
}

export default compose(
  withRouter,
)(Test)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function navigationExample() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
    
  return (
    <>
       <Button
          type="ice"
          text="WHITELIST"
          onCLick={() => navigate("/login")}
        />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Redirect component.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score 0):

you can use **useNavigate** function to navigate to the other page by simply using **useNavigate** from **react-router-dom** and navigate to the page you want
**first import it from react-router-dom library**

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
     
  const handleSubmit = () => {
     navigate("/routeName_that_you_wish_to_navigate_to");
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Button
          type="submit"
          text="Submit"
          onCLick={() => handleSubmit()}
        />
    </>
  );
}
```